# convert data pixels to image

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, pixel

I have a list of X-ray output data that I want to convert to an image. These numbers are diode data. data But with the methods I test, I do not get the right image with Python. My data is as follows:

```
 [[(2590),(2375),(2521),(2231),(2519),(2683),(2431),(2515)..(2555)],
 [(2443),(2468),(2227),(2428),(2623),(2419),(2469),(2336),..(2435)],
```

..
[(2133),(2381),(2291),(2346),(2303),(2403),(2434),(2336),..(2374)]
]

I put pixels into numpy array.
For example:1000*500

The size of each row and column is equal to the number of pixels in width and height.
Each of number is a pixel data.
Please help me how to convert?

Edit: Preliminary data:

[image]

Edit2:
This is the output data guide. Do I have to do any special preprocessing?

[image]

Comment: What is the pixel data? what does that number represent?

Comment: what exactly is the data format? Is it a list of lists? The way you posted requires the data to be stored in multiple variables.

Comment: numpy, reshape, rescale, done. please provide one set of complete data in some way.

Comment: Ok, I edited and put all the data.

Comment: the data is still the same as before. Specifically, the beginning should be `[[(` instead of `[(` for this to be data that can be stored in a single variable.

Comment: @Aoof , I don't know, and that's my problem.

Comment: @warped The data are the output of photodiodes that are returned linearly by X-rays. For example, there are 1152 pixels per line and 500 lines, for example.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I  put a picture of Preliminary data.

Comment: that's a screenshot of numbers. I'm not going to OCR that image. I was asking for data, i.e. the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all I am not sure what you mean by saving as a pixel data. If you ave a matrix say 2d numpy array you can already save it as an image file. Thus each element of the matrix will be a pixel value. I created my own small example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stf = [[(2590),(2375)], [(2443),(2468)]]
stf_arr = np.array(stf) # converting the list of lists to numpy array
stf_arr_rescaled = (255.0 / stf_arr.max() * (stf_arr - stf_arr.min())).astype(np.uint8)
plt.imshow(stf_arr) # visualization with matplotlib
# for saving the matrix itself
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromarray(stf_arr_rescaled)
im.save("stf_arr.png")
```

Comment: careful with the value ranges. all those numbers exceed the uint8 range.

Comment: Thanks for the note rescaled it now

Comment: @ShaigHamzaliyev, Thx, it is ok , The image that the driver displays is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plt.imshow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [[(2590),(2375),(2521)],
 [(2590),(2375),(2521)],
 [(2590),(2375),(2521)]]

plt.imshow(a)
# and then plt.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your response. But my output image is not what I expect. Could this data require special processing?

Comment: @nadiaprogrammer what exactly do you expect?

Comment: Xray image with an object inside it. But the images I convert are meaningless.